# Sublime Text 3 is Taking time for Execution

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: Screenshot of Simple Program taking 4.9s to Compile]

Sublime Text 3 is taking time to compile even a simple program like `cout<<"Hi\n";` Execution time is nearly 4-5s for simple programs. I have seen many Competitive Coders, their Sublime Text takes 0.8-1.2s to compile. I have searched over the internet but unable to fix it. Please help me out. How can I make it fast.

My Processor is not a Problem. I have Intel i7 9th Gen H Processor with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: All Sublime does is execute an external program and report how long it took. There's not a lot to be done to make it faster at that since it's not doing anything. By any chance are you using Windows while the other people with faster performance are using a different OS? Do either you or them have an SSD?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Windows 10. I am already using an SSD. I Guess PC Configuration is not a problem since I am using descent Processor i7 9750H, 16GB Ram, and 512 SSD. I have seen other people are using Linux or Mac. Is that affecting the Speed? I have observed for Linux. Mac users speed is very fast but for windows, it's a bit slow.

Comment: I don't have any hard evidence per se, but I've noticed that anything that requires starting a process or accessing files is much slower on Windows than it is on Linux. In any case, something to try would be to execute the command that Sublime is executing manually in a command prompt to see if that seems appreciably faster.